# How get data from sibling node

Tags: javascript

How do I get the value of an `<input>` tag contained within a clicked div or other element?  For example, in the code below, if a user clicks "Vote Up" or "Vote Down", how do I get or set the value of the sibling hidden `<input>`?

My code is:

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".up").click(function () {
                var vup = $(this).html();
                var qid = $(this).parent().getElementById("qid").value;;
                document.getElementById("sadas").innerHTML = qid + "<br>" + vup;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="question">
        <input id="qid" value="5" type="hidden">
            <a class="up" title="אם אתה מתחרט על הצבעה זו.">vote up</a>
            <b>0</b>
            <a class="up" title="אם שאלה זו שטוחה או פוגענית או חוזרת על עצמה או פשוטה." style="background-position:0 -220px;">vote down</a>
    </div>
    <div id="question">
        <input id="qid" value="6" type="hidden">
            <a class="up" title="אם אתה מתחרט על הצבעה זו.">vote up</a>
            <b>0</b>
            <a class="up" title="אם שאלה זו שטוחה או פוגענית או חוזרת על עצמה או פשוטה." style="background-position:0 -220px;">vote down</a>
    </div>
    <div id="sadas">sda</div>
```

Comment: The ID attribute in HTML must be unique. You aren't allowed to have two elements with the same ID.

Comment: jeskey, I edited your post, hopefully to make it more clear what you are asking.  Please review my edit and make sure it follows what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `id` values must be unique. I've replaced them with classes here.

You're on the right track. `find()` will find items matching a selector within your parent div:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".up").click(function() {
    var qid = $(this).parent().find(".qid").val();
    $('#sadas').
      text(qid).
      append('<br>' + $(this).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="question">
  <input class="qid" value="5" type="hidden">
  <a class="up" title="אם אתה מתחרט על הצבעה זו.">vote up</a>
  <b>0</b>
  <a class="up" title="אם שאלה זו שטוחה או פוגענית או חוזרת על עצמה או פשוטה." style="background-position:0 -220px;">vote down</a>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <input class="qid" value="6" type="hidden">
  <a class="up" title="אם אתה מתחרט על הצבעה זו.">vote up</a>
  <b>0</b>
  <a class="up" title="אם שאלה זו שטוחה או פוגענית או חוזרת על עצמה או פשוטה." style="background-position:0 -220px;">vote down</a>
</div>
<div id="sadas">sda</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below Code

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $(".up").click(function () {
                var vup = $(this).html();
                var closestdiv = $(this).closest("div");
                var qid = $(closestdiv).find("input:first").val();
                document.getElementById("sadas").innerHTML = qid + "<br>" + vup;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `$(div)` is redundant - `div` is already a jQuery object, being the result of `closest()`.

Answer (score 0):

I edited html elements in a correct way

[Answer in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzh08b50/2/)

```
<div class="question">
            <input class="qid" value="0" type="hidden">
                <a class="up" title="what ever">vote up</a>
                <b>0</b>
                <a class="down" title="what ever" >vote down</a>
</div>
   <hr>
<div class="question">
            <input class="qid" value="0" type="hidden">
                <a class="up" title="whatever">vote up</a>
                <b>0</b>
                <a class="down" title="whatever">vote down</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(".up").click(function () {
            var field = $(this).parent().find('.qid');
            var input_value = field.val();
            var new_value = parseInt(input_value) + 1;                
             field.val(new_value);
            $(this).parent().find('b').html(new_value);
        });
        $(".down").click(function () {
             var field = $(this).parent().find('.qid');
            var input_value = field.val();
            var new_value = parseInt(input_value) - 1;                
             field.val(new_value);
            $(this).parent().find('b').html(new_value);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: I assumed that this is the behavior you expect to have... ;)